# Can't Import Images Into Canvas

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, canvas, svg

I have to use a structure based on meteor and templates. That said: my Input button lets a user access an image on their computer. When the image should upload, the name of the selected image for upload is displayed outside the canvas, but no image appears on the canvas.

```
Error: document.getElementById(...).getContext is not a function

<template name="canvas">
  <div><input type="file" id="input"/></div>
  <div id='canvas'></div>
</template>
```

In a separate js file:

```
Canvas = function () {
  var self = this;
  var svg;

  var createSvg = function() {
    svg = d3.select('#canvas').append('svg')
      .attr('width', 1425)
      .attr('height',610);
  };
  createSvg();

  self.clear = function() {
    d3.select('svg').remove();
    createSvg();
  };

  self.draw = function(data) {
    if (data.length < 1) {
      self.clear();
      return;
    }
    if (svg) {


var input = document.getElementById('input');
input.addEventListener('change', handleFiles);

function handleFiles(e) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image;
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 20,20);
    }
}

      svg.selectAll('line').data(data, function(d) { return d._id; })
      .enter().append('line')
      .attr('x1', function (d) { return d.x; })
      .attr('y1', function (d) { return d.y; })
      .attr('x2', function (d) { return d.x1; })
      .attr('y2', function (d) { return d.y1; })
      .attr("stroke-width", function (d) { return d.w; })
      .attr("stroke", function (d) { return d.c; })
      .attr("opacity", function (d) { return d.o; })
      .attr("stroke-linecap", "round");

    }
  };
}
```

Various brushes, colors, etc. are in another separate js file.

```
Error: document.getElementById(...).getContext is not a function
```

Any help greatly appreciated. I am very new to all this.

Comment: You never create an HTMLCanvasElement, the only element that does have a `getContext` method. Currently you are calling it on a div, which should raise an error in your webConsole.

Comment: Thanks Kaiido. Works now, and so will a bunch of other things I was having trouble getting going.